# Why can't I add task and render it to the list?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Below is the code in which the "card-content" section there is a form to add the class and remove icon to remove the task.

When I try to add the task on adding the value to the form and click on the submit. The task is not getting added to the DOM. Javascript and HTML code for the reference.

app.js

```
function change(){
      var li = document.createElement("LI");
      var inputValue = document.getElementsByClassName("btn").value;
      var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
      li.appendChild(t);
      if (inputValue === ''){
          alert("Please input a task");
      }else{
          document.getElementsByClassName("collection").appendChild(li);
      }
      document.getElementsByClassName("btn").value = "";
      
      var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
      var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
      span.className = "close";
      span.appendChild(txt);
      li.appendChild(span);
      
      for(var k = 0;k < close.length;k++){
        close[k].onclick = function(){
            var div = this.parentElement;
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    var myNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for(var i = 0;i < myNodeList.length;i++){
        var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
        var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
        span.className = "close";
        span.appendChild(txt);
        myNodeList[i].appendChild(span);
    }

    var close = document.getElementsByClassName("fa fa-remove");
    for(var j = 0;j < close.length;j++){
        close[j].onclick = function(){
            var div = this.parentElement;
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

HTML file to add task to the list based on the User Input.
indes.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Task List</title>
      <style>
        .red{
          color:red;
        }
        .blue{
          color:blue;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
            <div id="main" class="card">
              <div class="card-content">
                <span class="card-title">Task List TEST</span>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                      <input type="text" name="task" id="task">
                      <label for="task">New Task</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" onclick="change()" value="Add Task" class="btn">
              </div>
              <div class="card-action">
                <h5 id="task-title">Tasks</h5>
                <ul class="collection">
                  <li class="collection-item">
                    List Item
                    <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                      <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li> 
                  <li class="collection-item">
                    List Item
                    <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                      <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li> 
                  <li class="collection-item">
                    List Item
                    <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                      <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="collection-item">
                    List Item
                    <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                      <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="collection-item">
                    List Item
                    <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                      <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
              
                </ul>
                <a class="clear-tasks btn black" href="">Clear Tasks</a>
                <button onclick="change()" class="test">Change</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>//The Javascript being used//

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using "getElementsByClassName" function you need to specify the exact index position, Refer below

```
document.getElementsByClassName("collection")[0].appendChild(li);
```

Comment: will it work if I used ```document.querySelectorAll(".collection").appendChild(li);``` ?

Comment: No, QuerySelector also provides array of elements